# Problem with retrieving row data of my ag-grid by double clicking the row, written by angular 11

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I used ag grid in my angular project. I want to retrieve double clicked row data and copy it to a variable but in the end it shows [object Object] instead of my row data.

here is my codes:

`.html` file:

```
<p>data:{{rowsSelection}}</p>
<ag-grid-angular    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
                    class="ag-theme-balham"
                    [rowData]="rowdata"
                    [columnDefs]="gridOptions.columnDefs"
                    [defaultColDef]="gridOptions.defaultColDef"
                    [enableRtl]="agGridPropeties.enableRTL"
                    [localeText]="localeTextPersian"
                    [rowSelection]="agGridPropeties.rowSelection"
                    [multiSortKey]="agGridPropeties.multiSortKey"
                    [pagination]="agGridPropeties.pagination"
                    [paginationPageSize]="agGridPropeties.paginationPageSize"
                    enableCharts="true"
                    rowDragManaged="true"
                    animateRows="true"
                    [sideBar]="sideBar"
                    (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)'
                    (cellClicked)='onCellClicked($event)'
                    (selectionChanged) = 'onSelectionChanged($event)'
                    (rowDoubleClicked) = 'onRowDoubleClicked($event)'
                    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

`.ts` file :

```
constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {
  this.newData();
}

public newData() {
  this.auth.getallunits().subscribe(result => {
    this.rowdata = result.data;
  });
}

public onRowDoubleClicked(event: any) { 
  this.rowsSelection = {'data':event};
  console.log({'doubleClicked': event});
}
```

In console i can see the data but inside `p` tag I see [object Object]!

here is the console.log result:

```
doubleClicked:
api: GridApi {detailGridInfoMap: {…}, destroyCalled: false, immutableService: ImmutableService, csvCreator: CsvCreator, excelCreator: null, …}
columnApi: ColumnApi {columnController: ColumnController}
context: undefined
data: {Unit_Code: 20003, Unit_Title_Persian: "بسته 4 عددی", Conversion_factor: 4, Parent_Unit_ID: 10001}
event: MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1025, screenY: 866, clientX: 1025, clientY: 763, …}
node: RowNode {childrenMapped: {…}, selectable: true, __objectId: 4, alreadyRendered: true, highlighted: null, …}
rowIndex: 3
rowPinned: undefined
source: RowComp {destroyFunctions: Array(37), destroyed: false, __v_skip: true, getContext: ƒ, isAlive: ƒ, …}
type: "rowDoubleClicked"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

and inside my `p` tag :

```
data:[object Object]
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use `event.node.data` instead of `event`:

```
public onRowDoubleClicked(event: any) { 
  this.rowsSelection = event.node.data.Unit_Code;
  console.log({'doubleClicked': event.node.data});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event handler should be

```
onRowDoubleClicked(row) { 
  this.rowsSelection = {data: row.data};
  console.log('doubleClicked', row.data);
}
```